# Why does this nodejs code output in the same order regardless of which function comes first?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In this code, no matter what order I put the functions, the files in the directory are always printed before the name of the directory:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.realpath(__dirname, function(err, path) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Path is : ' + path);
});

fs.readdir(__dirname, function(err, files) {
    if (err) return;
    files.forEach(function(f) {
        console.log('File: ' + f);
    });
});

File: text_1.txt
File: text_2.txt
File: text_3.txt
Path: /home/user/docs
```

So, If fs.readdir() was the first function the output would be the same. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions are [asynchronous](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/), so the order you put them in the file has little to do with the order in which the operations are performed. The `readdir` operation is probably much faster, so it is getting completed before the `realpath` operation.

In order to perform these operations in order, you can put the calls to one inside the callback of the other.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.realpath(__dirname, function(err, path) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Path is : ' + path);
    fs.readdir(__dirname, function(err, files) {
        if (err) return;
        files.forEach(function(f) {
            console.log('File: ' + f);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the synchronous versions, realpathSync() and readdirSync() and, no output returned. How would I get return values then?

Comment: Instead of using synchronous functions, I recommend nesting the callbacks. I've updated my answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, Will. I'm just curious though, why do the synchronous functions skip the output?

Comment: They don't—they return it.

Comment: But, the console.log() statements don't show up in the terminal like they did before.

Comment: Exactly—it returns it. Run `console.log(fs.readdirSync(__dirname));`

Comment: It's interesting that the inner console.log() gets canceled out in this case:   console.log(fs.readdirSync(__dirname, function (err, files) {
      if (err) return;
      files.forEach(function (f) {
          console.log('File: ' + f);
      });
  }));     Any insight as to how that happens?

Comment: @user465001: The synchronous version simply ignores the second argument (the function) you pass to it. It is never called. Here is a simple example that does the same: `function foo() { return 42;}; foo(function() { console.log('gets never called'); });`.